# call the same jQuery function in multiple link <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I am not really familiar with jQuery.
the idea is
link a `href="..?episode=1"`will be add class `active`, while the other link will not be  add class active
link a `href='..?episode=2"` will be added  class `active`, while the other link will not be active add class
Similar to other links. I have code html

```
<ul id="episode">
    <li><a  href="index.php?episode=1" class="active">1</a></li>
    <li><a  href="index.php?episode=2">2</a></li>
    <li><a  href="index.php?episode=3">3</a></li>
    <li><a  href="index.php?episode=4">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

code js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(){
        if($("a").text()!="1"){
            $("a.active1").removeClass("active1");
            $("a").addClass("active1");
            alert($(this)).text();
        }
    })
})
```

The problem is when one episode is selected, the message pops up 2 times and class are added to and then is removed.I do not know what the reason is? there i can tell me one way is no solution

Comment: so you want to add the active class to only that link which is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

Use this snippet:

What it does it remove active class from all `a` elements and then adds active class to the currently clicked one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(){
      $("a").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="episode">
    <li><a  href="#" class="active">1</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have changed `href` so it will work here, feel free to use your original html layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('#episode');
    var $links = $wrapper.find('a');

    $wrapper.on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        var $active = $(e.currentTarget);

        $links.removeClass('active');
        $active.addClass('active');
        alert($active.text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I advise you to read a little about [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) in jquery, because if this list gets big, you are wasting resources.

Second, you should use `this`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul").on('click', 'a', function () {
        $("a.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

and this should work and be efficient. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your jQuery code is not correct and corrected code is as below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(){
    if($(this).text()!="1"){
        $("a.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        alert($(this).text());
    }
 });
});
```

For the fix for your problem check http://jsfiddle.net/sacmonk/o7dv0cm4/

Comment: You only fixed text in `alert` problem, not what OP is actually asking about.

Answer (score 0):

> **Use  .find('a')**

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/gnnudnu7/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li a').click(function () {
        $('#episode').find('a').removeClass('active')
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })
    })
```